# How to fix infinite loop with a WINAPI function?

Tags: c++, loops, winapi, timeout

I'm trying to code a timeout function that kicks out the user if he doesn't select any options in a given amount of time. However I'm finding myself stuck in a infinite loop and even my wait timer can't destroy the loop.

My code:

```
namespace jsw {
    namespace threading {
        class auto_event {
        public:
            auto_event() : _event(CreateEvent(0, false, false, 0)) {}

            BOOL wait(DWORD timeout = 1) const
            {
                return WaitForSingleObject(_event, timeout) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
            }

            BOOL set() { return SetEvent(_event); }
            BOOL reset_event() { return ResetEvent(_event); }
        private:
            HANDLE _event;
        };

        class thread {
        public:
            static thread start(
                LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE fn, LPVOID args = 0,
                DWORD state = 0, DWORD timeout = 5000)
            {
                return thread(CreateThread(0, 0, fn, args, state, 0), timeout);
            }

            static void sleep(DWORD milliseconds) { Sleep(milliseconds); }
            static void exit(DWORD exitCode) { ExitThread(exitCode); }
        public:
            thread(HANDLE thread, DWORD timeout) : _thread(thread), _timeout(timeout) {}
            ~thread() { CloseHandle(_thread); }

            DWORD exit_code() const
            {
                DWORD exitCode = NO_ERROR;

                GetExitCodeThread(_thread, &exitCode);

                return exitCode;
            }

            HANDLE handle() const { return _thread; }
            BOOL is_alive() const { return exit_code() == STILL_ACTIVE; }
            DWORD join() { return WaitForSingleObject(_thread, _timeout); }
            DWORD suspend() { return SuspendThread(_thread); }
            DWORD resume() { return ResumeThread(_thread); }
            BOOL abort(DWORD exitCode) { return TerminateThread(_thread, exitCode); }
        private:
            HANDLE _thread;
            DWORD _timeout;
        };
    }
}


DWORD WINAPI get_option(LPVOID args)
{
    using namespace jsw::threading;

    int* option = (int*)((LPVOID*)args)[0];
    auto_event* e = (auto_event*)((LPVOID*)args)[1];

    std::cin >> *option;
    e->set();

    return NO_ERROR;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace jsw::threading;

    int option{};
    auto_event e;
    LPVOID args[2] = { &option, &e };

    thread worker = thread::start(get_option, args);

    if (e.wait(5000)) {
        do {
            system("cls");

            switch (option) {
            case 1: // Do some stuff...
                break;
            case 2: // Do some stuff...
                break;
            case 3: // Exit
                break;
            default: std::cout << "Option not valid!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        } while (option != 3);
        std::cout << "***Program Exit***" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        worker.abort(NO_ERROR);
        std::cout << "***PROGRAM END***\n";
    }
}
```

I managed to make the loop work in the get_option function; however I had a problem with the timeout function since it couldn't work in it, so I decided to put the loop in the main function, yet nothing works.

So if possible can somebody tell me how to fix this infinite loop and the timer?

Comment: The thread function `get_option` doesn't have a loop. After the first input it will exit and never run again. From that point onward, the value of `option` will never ever change.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to fix it (at least a bit) but my timer still doesn't kick out the user if no answer is given in the amount of time specified. Is there a perhaps a solution to that?

Comment: @RexyCode Since we don't know what `jsw::threading::thread` is or how its `abort()` method works, there is no way to answer that. However, for what you are attempting to do, I would suggest getting rid of the thread altogether and use Win32 Console API functions directly to read the input instead of using C++ I/O.  You can perform non-blocking waits using the Console API, but C++ I/O is always blocking.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited the code so that you can understand how the abort() function works and I probably should have specified that I'm new to C++ so I don't know how to really use the API is it possile for you to give me an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) said,

> the thread function `get_option` doesn't have a loop. After the first
> input it will exit and never run again.

You can put the **input method(get_option)** in a loop, here I used the `while` for your reference.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace jsw::threading;

    int option{};
    auto_event e;
    LPVOID args[2] = { &option, &e };

    while (true)
    {
        thread worker = thread::start(get_option, args);

        if (e.wait(5000)) {
            //do {
                //system("cls");

                switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    std::cout << "Option 1" << std::endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    std::cout << "Option 2" << std::endl;
                    break;
                case 3: // Exit
                    break;
                default: std::cout << "Option not valid!" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
            //} while (option != 3);
            //std::cout << "***Program Exit***" << std::endl;
            //break;
        }
        else {
            worker.abort(NO_ERROR);
            std::cout << "***PROGRAM END***\n";
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code it works well, the timer kicks out the user if no input is given in the first 5s, which is good, however after the user inputs one thing and then waits for another 5s the timer doesn't kick him out anymore. Do you perhaps have a solution for that?

Comment: Have you added `break;` after `worker.abort(NO_ERROR);`

Comment: Somehow when I copied the code I forgot the `break;` statement, however now the code works great so thank you a lot!

Comment: The code certainly doesn't work reliably (the documentation for [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) *explicitly* tells you not to use it). But hey, that's what you get when you aim for cheap, and hire folks that don't understand Microsoft technologies to answer questions about Microsoft technologies. Good job, MSFT!

Comment: @IInspectable Do you have a more reliable way to accomplish the same thing? If it is the case could you please share it? I would really like to make something that is well optimized and works well without cutting corners.

Comment: Don't use multithreading. Windows' I/O system is asynchronous; no need to burn extra cycles on a needless thread. That'll also mean that you cannot use C++' I/O streams library. Not a big loss given how poorly it is designed.

Comment: @IInspectable Like I stated previously I am new to programming so could you please provide a small block of code to illustrate your point ?